# Clearing a char array of sensitive data from memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory, char

Is there a difference in benefit for "zeroing out" a char array so it doesn't stay in memory using `Arrays.fill(password, 0)` instead of using `password = null`?  I'm not asking why use a char array instead of a String.  I'm asking why set the values to 0 instead of setting the array to null.  Is it because setting the values to 0 immediately changes the value in memory, while null doesn't immediately change the value to null in memory, but instead just waits for it to be garbage collected?  Would it make sense to set the values to 0 then immediately set it to null as well so that it gets garbage collected, instead of sitting around as an array of 0's?

Comment: Setting a variable to null doesn't erase the object from memory until the GC kicks in.

Comment: I could have sworn someone asked a question about this before, but I would think zeroing out the array would be better than re-referencing the object, as you can be sure that the memory has been changed and doesn't have to wait until it's garbage collected.

Comment: @shmosel That was the question I was referring to, thanks!

Comment: I'm not asking why use a char array instead of a string.  I'm asking why set the values to 0 instead of setting the array to null.  None of those answers clarify this difference.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: It's the same reason. Because reference cleanups have to wait for the GC.

Answer (score 0):

No, whatever the value of each char, the array is still maintain in memory and thus consume it.

Defining the reference to null **may** lead to GC election if it was the last reference to this array.

On the other hand, if you have security concerns, resetting each char before freeing the reference is a best practice.

You can read more about [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Comment: For the benefit of others: "*may*" is a keyword here. There is no guarantee GC will be invoked.